# How to display form field on condition using PHP in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

I have select input in my form for manufacturers.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="manufacturer">Manufacturer</label>
    <select id="manufacturerSelect" name="manufacturer" class="form-control">
        <option disabled selected value> -- select an manufacturer -- </option>
        <?php foreach ($manufacturers as $manufacturers_item): ?>
            <option value="<?=$manufacturers_item['id'];?>" <?php echo set_select('manufacturer',$manufacturers_item['id'], ( !empty($manufacturer) && $manufacturer == $manufacturers_item['id'] ? TRUE : FALSE )); ?> ><?=$manufacturers_item['name'];?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
         <option disabled>──────────</option>
        <option value="24" <?php echo set_select('manufacturer','24', ( !empty($manufacturer) && $manufacturer == '24' ? TRUE : FALSE )); ?> >Other</option>
    </select>
    <?php echo form_error('manufacturer'); ?><br />
</div>
```

If "other" (value == 24) is checked additional input is asked:

```
$('body').on('change', '#manufacturerSelect', function() { 
    if ($(this).val() == 24) {
        $("#otherManufacturerSelect").removeClass('hidden');
    } else {
        $("#otherManufacturerSelect").addClass('hidden')
    }
});
```

And HTML:

```
<div id="otherManufacturerSelect"  class="form-group">
    <label for="otherManufacturer" >What is it then?</label>
    <input type="text" name="otherManufacturer" class="form-control">
    <?php echo form_error('otherManufacturer'); ?><br />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden {
    display: hidden;
}
```

Now if user picks "other" as manufacturer addition input is displayed. Form validation rule for otherManufacturer is added in server side if `manufacturer == 24`. The problem is that the other manufacturer input is displayed every time user get response from server. I could add `class="hidden"` by default to other manufacturer div but if the form validation doesnt run other manufacturer field will not be displayed again to user.

What I need is PHP IF condition inside:

`<div id="otherManufacturerSelect" <?php if(/*???*/):?>class="hidden"<?php endif; ?> class="form-group">`

So that `class="hidden"` would be added only if manufacturer is not "other". but I cannt think of rigth condition.

Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT**

Controller:

```
public function create()
{
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('manufacturer', 'Manufacturer', 'required');
    if($this->input->post('manufacturer') == '24'){
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('otherManufacturer', 'Other manufacturer', 'required');
    }

    $data['manufacturers'] = $this->puzzles_model->getManufacturers();

    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('puzzles/create', $data);
    }
    else
    {
        /* do the upload, return upload errors or save in db*/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your particular case this would fix the problem:

```
<div id="otherManufacturerSelect" class="form-group <?php if(isset($manufacturer) && $manufacturer !== '24') { echo 'hidden'; } ?> ">
    <label for="otherManufacturer" >What is it then?</label>
    <input type="text" name="otherManufacturer" class="form-control">
    <?php echo form_error('otherManufacturer'); ?><br />
</div>
```

Then you can remove the JS snippet. The additional form will be hidden on server side (class="hidden" will be set).

I saw that you're using var $manufacturer in the same template. I can't see your controller and how you're passing variables but instead of $manufacturer you can also use $_GET['manufacturer'] or $_POST['manufacturer'] (depending on your form action method).
Notice: $_GET['manufacturer'], $_POST['manufacturer'] and $_REQUEST['manufacturer'] is NOT sanitized input. When using $manufacturer I assume that it's sanitized in your controller.

Comment: `Message: syntax error, unexpected ''hidden'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'`

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my answer. It works now. I'm using the shorthand syntax for if statements. If your PHP version doesn't allows it you can replace it with: <? if($manufacturer !== '24') { echo 'hidden'; }  ?>

Comment: I think tou meant `<?php if($manufacturer !== '24') { echo 'hidden'; } ?>`. However no matter which approach I use I get this error: `Message: Undefined variable: manufacturer`

Comment: You are using the same variable in the same template (few lines above). Anyways if the form is not submitted you won't have the variable. Please add <?php if(!empty($manufacturer)  && isset($manufacturer) && $manufacturer !== '24') { echo 'hidden'; } ?>

Comment: I think that `isset` would be moved before `empty` in `IF` condition

Comment: Sure, even only isset check is ebough:  <?php if(isset($manufacturer) && $manufacturer !== '24') { echo 'hidden'; } ?>

Comment: While I totally understand your approach I still can not get it working. It doesnot add "hidden" class. I tried `<?php if(isset($manufacturer) && $manufacturer !== '24') { echo 'hidden'; }else { echo 'not_hidden';}  ?>` and inspecting the element I get "not_hidden" in every possible case. I updated question with controller, would really appreciate I you could take a look on that!

Comment: Ok, you need to pass the variable to your template before loading it from the Controller like so:

    $data['manufacturer']=$this->input->post('manufacturer');
    $this->load->view('puzzles/create', $data);

Comment: I figured it out! `<?php if($manufacturer !== '24') { echo 'hidden'; } ?>` without isset part because I use `<option disabled selected value> -- select an manufacturer -- </option>` so on first time the form is displayed the manufacturer can not be set so condition doesnt run. Also I have to add JS snippet because if user chooses "other" he needs to be promted to enter "other" emidiatelly not after submitting form - it would be bad user experience.

Comment: I'm glad you did it. Sure, the first time the form is displayed $manufacturer won't be set - we are setting it only after form submission (it's derived from $_POST)